# Global reference to object on Click() sub (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there's a way to refer to the object of the "Click()" sub.

To make it clearer, let's say we have a button named foo1 and this button has a click sub "foo1_Click()". Does vba has a keyword to get the reference to foo1 that is global?

Something like:

```
Public Sub foo1_Click()

GlobalKeyword.Property

End Sub
```

P.s.: something like the word "this" from java refering to its own instance of class

Edit: In the example, the "GlobalKeyword" would refer to "foo1"

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `Application.Caller` property found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx).

In your case you would want to do something like....

```
Public Sub foo1_Click()
    Dim button As Shape
    Set button = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Shapes(Application.Caller)
End Sub
```

Of course after that you would want to do some error checking to make sure `button` is not nothing.

If you want to use the same code for a lot of buttons, then you may be better of using a separate subroutine.

```
Private Sub foo1_Click()
    Call do_something
End Sub

Private Sub foo2_Click()
    Call do_something
End Sub

Sub do_something() 'called by the foo _Click event

    MsgBox Application.Caller

End Sub
```

This way, you it is easy to maintain the core functionality for all buttons simply by updating the `do_something` procedure.

Comment: I see. It's just that I wanted to copy and paste the same piece of code to alot of buttons, that's why I wanted to use global keywords.

Comment: Copy/paste code isn't always the best answer. If you need to change something in the copied code, you need to change it in more than one place and that's not ideal. I've found that when I think I need to copy/paste some code a bunch of times there is usually a better solution.

Comment: @GuilhermeRisnikRomeiro I made some additional revision to Taelsin's answer if that's what you're getting at...

Comment: @DavidZemens Awesome! I didn't realize that would work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It may need some tweaking still, but the principle of using a dedicated subroutine *from* an event procedure like `_Click` should work :)